# What's the good architecture for ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash, apache-kafka, kibana

I am trying to use ELK to build a log analysis system. I see a lot of architecture which use ELK in different way. one of them is

Logstash->Redis->Logstash->Elasticseach->Kibana

The first Logstash is used for collecting logs, the second Logstash is used for filter logs.

I am not very clear about the Redis, Do we have to use it? Why not using Kafka?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redis between the two logstash instances is a buffer, just there in case elasticsearch or the logstash indexer goes down.

Depending on what you're processing with logstash, you may not need it.  If you're reading log files, logstash (the shipper) will stop sending logs when logstash (the indexer) is overwhelmed.  This way, you get a distributed cache (in your log files!).

If you're using one-time events (e.g. traps or syslogs from network devices), then the buffer like redis or rabbitmq would be important to store them until logstash (indexer) is available.

Answer (score 0):

The second logstash is used to tokenize logs and transform them from lines of logs to parsed JSONs.

Regarding architecture, there are a couple of other things you may want to consider like security, mapping, scalability. You can have a look at a blog post I wrote on how deploy ELK in production (http://logz.io/blog/deploy-elk-production/)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can just find the simple **Setup of ELK** (`if doesn't need of Redis`). You can go through the below link for full setup and and how to load the logs using **logstash** and search the logs using **elsticsearch** and make the visulizations in **Kibana**

[ELK Setup Installation](http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/elasticsearch/install-elasticsearch-kibana-logstash-on-windows.html)